# Deployment failed : An object 'My lightning js object' of type AuraDefinitionBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: deployment

Can anyone help me so I can deploy? I have this deployment failure:

> An object  of type AuraDefinitionBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Comment: With the limited information you have in here, the error suggests that you have a component mentioned in your package.xml but not in the zipped directory. It will be relevant here to provide a bit of details around the exact message, and how are you trying to deploy and what components you are trying to deploy. Please [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/258051/edit) to provide those details for anyone to be able to help you here.

Comment: @JayantDas, i try to deploy by this command: $ java -jar po-0.1.jar -e MyEnv -f ../MySrc -sdgx -t NoTestRun

Comment: I try to deploy Aura component